# Large SQL database - solving efficiency

Tags: mysql, performance

I have this following SQL query, which, when I originally coded it, was exceptionally fast, it now takes over 1 second to complete:

```
SELECT counted/scount as ratio, [etc]
    FROM 
        playlists 
    LEFT JOIN (
        select AID, PLID FROM (SELECT AID, PLID FROM p_s ORDER BY `order` asc, PLSID desc)as g GROUP BY PLID 
    ) as t USING(PLID)

    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT PLID, count(PLID) as scount from p_s LEFT JOIN audio USING(AID) WHERE removed='0' and verified='1' GROUP BY PLID
    ) as g USING(PLID)

    LEFT JOIN (
        select AID, count(AID) as counted FROM a_p_all WHERE ".time()." - playtime < 2678400 GROUP BY AID
    ) as r USING(AID)

    LEFT JOIN audio USING (AID)

    LEFT JOIN members USING (UID)

    WHERE scount > 4 ORDER BY ratio desc

    LIMIT 0, 20
```

I have identified the problem, the `a_p_all` table has over 500k rows. This is slowing down the query. I have come up with a solution:

- Create a smaller temporary table, that only stores the data necessary, and deletes anything older than is needed.

However, is there a better method to use? Optimally I wouldn't need a temporary table; what do sites such as YouTube/Facebook do for large tables to keep query times fast?

---

### edit

This is the EXPLAIN table for the query in the answer from @spencer7593

```
id    select_type    table     type    possible_keys    key    key_len    ref    rows    Extra 
1      PRIMARY     <derived3>   ALL        NULL         NULL    NULL      NULL    20
1      PRIMARY         u       eq_ref    PRIMARY      PRIMARY     8     q.AID     1     Using index
1      PRIMARY         m       eq_ref    PRIMARY      PRIMARY     8      q.UID    1     Using index
3      DERIVED     <derived6>   ALL        NULL         NULL    NULL     NULL     20
6      DERIVED         t        ALL        NULL         NULL    NULL     NULL     21
5 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   s        ALL        NULL         NULL    NULL     NULL     49    Using where; Using filesort
4 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   c        ALL        NULL         NULL    NULL     NULL     49    Using where
4 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   o      eq_ref      PRIMARY     PRIMARY     8 database.c.AID 1    Using where
2 DEPENDENT SUBQUERY   a        ALL        NULL         NULL    NULL     NULL   510594  Using where
```

Comment: Can you post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` statements for the involved tables, in particular for `a_p_all` and whichever other table it joins with (`p_s` and `audio`, it looks like?) ?

Comment: And also please post the `EXPLAIN` for this query.

Comment: Larger apps don't use 1 database on 1 computer, they simply distribute everything. Each such node is filled with lots of RAM, and everything is kept in RAM (that requires fast access). Materialized views are used (similar to what you almost did with temp table), and most "on the fly" calculations are avoided. For example, I'd probably keep that query (after further optimization) if I were you and I'd just periodically execute it and then save those 20 results to a table that I'd use for reading only. That way I saved lots of time, plus logic is simplified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two "big rock" issues stand out to me.

Firstly, this predicate

```
 WHERE ".time()." - playtime < 2678400
```

(I'm assuming that this isn't the actual SQL being submitted to the database, but that what's being sent to the database is something like this...

```
 WHERE 1409192073 - playtime < 2678400
```

such that we want only rows where `playtime` is within the past 31 days (i.e. within 31*24*60*60 seconds of the integer value returned by `time()`.

This predicate can't make use of a range scan operation on a suitable index on `playtime`. MySQL evaluates the expression on the left side for *every* row in the table (every row that isn't excluded by some other predicate), and the result of that expression is compared to the literal on the right.

To improve performance, rewrite the predicate that so that the comparison is made on the **bare column**. Compare the value stored in the `playtime` column to an expression that needs to be evaluated one time, for example:

```
WHERE playtime > 1409192073 - 2678400
```

With a suitable index available, MySQL can perform a "range" scan operation, and efficiently eliminate a boatload of rows that don't need to be evaluated.

---

The second "big rock" is the inline views, or "derived tables" in MySQL parlance. MySQL is much different than other databases in how inline views are processed. MySQL actually runs that innermost query, and stores the result set as a temporary MyISAM table, and then the outer query runs against the MyISAM table. (The name that MySQL uses, "derived table", makes sense when we understand how MySQL processes the inline view.) Also, MySQL does not "push" predicates down, from an outer query down into the view queries. And on the derived table, there are no indexes created. (I believe MySQL 5.7 is changing that, and does sometimes create indexes, to improve performance.) But large "derived tables" can have a significant performance impact.

---

Also, the LIMIT clause gets applied last in the statement processing; that's after all the rows in the resultset are prepared and sorted. Even if you are returning only 20 rows, MySQL still prepares the entire resultset; it just doesn't transfer them to the client.

---

Lots of the column references are not qualified with the table name or alias, so we don't know, for example, which table (`p_s` or `audio`) contains the `removed` and `verified` columns.

(We know it can't be both, if MySQL isn't throwing a "ambiguous column" error. But MySQL has access to the table definitions, where we don't. MySQL also knows something about the cardinality of the columns, in particular, which columns (or combination of columns) are UNIQUE, and which columns can contain NULL values, etc.

Best practice is to qualify ALL column references with the table name or (preferably) a table alias. (This makes it much easier on the human reading the SQL, and it also avoids a query from breaking when a new column is added to a table.)

---

Also, the query as a `LIMIT` clause, but there's no `ORDER BY` clause (or implied ORDER BY), which makes the resultset indeterminate. We don't have any guaranteed which will be the "first" rows returned.

---

**EDIT**

To return only 20 rows from playlists (out of thousands or more), I might try using correlated subqueries in the SELECT list; using a LIMIT clause in an inline view to winnow down the number of rows that I'd need to run the subqueries for. Correlated subqueries can eat your lunch (and your lunchbox too) in terms of performance with large sets, due to the number of times those need to be run.

From what I can gather, you are attempting to return 20 rows from `playlists`, picking up the related row from member (by the foreign key in playlists), finding the "first" song in the playlist; getting a count of times that "song" has been played in the past 31 days (from any playlist); getting the number of times a song appears on that playlist (as long as it's been verified and hasn't been removed... the outerness of that LEFT JOIN is negated by the predicates on the `removed` and `verified` columns, if either of those columns is from the `audio` table...).

I'd take a shot with something like this, to compare performance:

```
SELECT q.*
     , ( SELECT COUNT(1) 
           FROM a_p_all a
          WHERE a.playtime < 1409192073 - 2678400
            AND a.AID = q.AID
       ) AS counted
  FROM ( SELECT p.PLID
              , p.UID
              , p.[etc]
              , ( SELECT COUNT(1) 
                    FROM p_s c
                    JOIN audio o
                      ON o.AID = c.AID
                     AND o.removed='0'
                     AND o.verified='1'
                   WHERE c.PLID = p.PLID
                ) AS scount
              , ( SELECT s.AID
                    FROM p_s s
                   WHERE s.PLID = p.PLID
                   ORDER BY s.order ASC, s.PLSID DESC 
                   LIMIT 1
                ) AS AID
           FROM ( SELECT t.PLID
                       , t.[etc]
                    FROM playlists t
                   ORDER BY NULL 
                   LIMIT 20
                ) p
       ) q
  LEFT JOIN audio u ON u.AID = q.AID
  LEFT JOIN members m ON m.UID = q.UID
 LIMIT 0, 20
```

**UPDATE**

Dude, the `EXPLAIN` output is showing that you don't have suitable indexes available. To get any decent chance at performance with the correlated subqueries, you're going to want to add some indexes, e.g.

```
... ON a_p_all (AID, playtime)

... ON p_s (PLID, order, PLSID, AID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response, I'm working through each point 1 by 1. I wanted to mention though, for the first point, I altered the code to `playtime > 1409192073 - 2678400` as specified, however, this is actually slowing down the query. So I decided to try  `1409192073 - 2678400 < playtime`, this was actually 25% faster over repeated trials.

Comment: That's really odd, I've never observed that behavior before. The order of the expressions in a comparison shouldn't make any difference. MySQL should process `a < b` the same as `b > a`. The performance boost should come from having a suitable index available, and a significant reduction in the number of rows that need to be returned. If you only need 20 rows from playlist, and there are significantly more rows than that (in the thousands), you may actually get better performance with a query using correlated subqueries in the SELECT list.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I have given it a go, and the query time has increased substantially to approximately 10 seconds. I will add the EXPLAIN into my initial post

Comment: I have added in the EXPLAIN, I also do have an ORDER BY statement that I added to the original query

Comment: The EXPLAIN output is showing that there aren't any indexes available on `a_p_all` or `p_s`. You're going to need suitable indexes to have any chance of performance with the correlated subqueries in my example SQL.

Comment: I added indexes, and tested your query, and the query time from my original code went from ~0.7s to ~0.01s. That is awesome, thanks for the help.

Comment: @JimmyBanks: Just to re-emphasize: subqueries in a SELECT list (as in my example) can be a HUGE performance problem. The "trick" in my statement is that you are only pulling 20 rows from playlists (there's a LIMIT in the inline view query, so those correlated subqueries will be executed a maximum of 20 times. For larger sets, those would kill performance, with the sheer number of times each gets executed (once for each row). If you needed all rows from playlists, then you'd much likely be better off with the JOIN operations.)